# Hibernate - how to return objects not tracked by session?

Tags: performance, hibernate

In Entity Framework there is an option called [AutoDetectChangesEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.autodetectchangesenabled%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) which significantly improves performance when performing bulk operations.

Is there any equivalent in Hibernate, which could improve performance while selecting/inserting many records to the database?
Or maybe the question should be, is such really needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options:

- `Session.setDefaultReadOnly()` - looks like a direct equivalent of `AutoDetectChangesEnabled`. However, it only disables detection of changes, but keeps session cache enabled, because it's needed for other features. So, it only affects performance, but not memory consumption.
- `StatelessSession` - has no session cache (doesn't keep references to entities at all), and lacks many features of regular `Session` because of that
- Another common approach to this problem is to `clear()` the session periodically (say, after each 100 entities) during processing (or `evict()` individual entities manually). This approach combines advantages of previous options, because it keeps normal semantics of `Session` while discarding entities when they are no longer needed